Programatically update cluster name value in /.kube/config file?
K3s does not have an option to pre-define the cluster name and kubectl does not allow to changing it programmatically. Therefore, I used the test playbook listed below to modify the cluster name.
My goal is to replace the default cluster name, with homelab. K3s original configuration, using default as cluster name:
$ cat /tmp/k3s.yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FUR
    server: https://192.168.1.2:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FU
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBFQyBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0t

Ansible Playbook
- name: Update kubeconfig
  hosts: apollo
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Create temp file
      ansible.builtin.tempfile:
        prefix: kubeconfig.
      register: kubeconfig

    - name: Copy kubeconfig file
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: /tmp/k3s.yaml
        dest: '{{ kubeconfig.path }}'
        mode: preserve
        remote_src: true

    - name: Get file content
      ansible.builtin.slurp:
        path: '{{ kubeconfig.path }}'
      register: file

    - name: Set datasource fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        datasource: '{{ file.content | b64decode | from_yaml }}'

    - name: Set datasource parameters
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        datasource: '{{ datasource | combine(parameters) }}'
      vars:
        parameters:
          clusters:
            - cluster:
                certificate-authority-data: "{{ datasource.clusters[0].cluster['certificate-authority-data'] }}"
                server: '{{ datasource.clusters[0].cluster.server }}'
              name: homelab
          contexts:
            - context:
                cluster: homelab
                user: '{{ datasource.contexts[0].context.user }}'
              name: '{{ datasource.contexts[0].name }}'

    - name: Update configuration
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: '{{ datasource | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}'
        dest: '{{ kubeconfig.path }}'
        mode: preserve
        remote_src: true

To my knowledge, there is no way to update YAML data directly, so I'm forced to save the datasource into a dictionary, then combine the data. Which produces the expected results:
$ cat /tmp/kubeconfig.iihidl73
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FUR
    server: https://192.168.1.2:6443
  name: homelab
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: homelab
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FU
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBFQyBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0t

Is there a better way to do this, without being forced to explicitly define the cluster.certificate-authority-data and cluster.server keys? As a side note, I was forced to use to_nice_yaml(indent=2) because b64decode sets the indent to 4.
